# If one element in an array is clicked then add a class to the same nth other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want an item to show when a link is clicked.  I have made an array of all of the links.

I want to add the class "show" to an array of `<div>`s. Potentially if the solution makes more sense the `<div>`'s could be within the anchor, it doesn't matter they will overlay the screen.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <a href="#"> <!-- lot's of <a>'s will make the array -->
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-item--inner-container">
                <div class="grid-item--normal-content">
                        <div class="grid-item--heading">
                            <h2>Lending Creativity</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-item--border">&nbsp;</div>
                </div><!-- end normal content -->
            </div><!-- Grid-item-inner -->
        </div><!-- Grid item -->
    </a>
~
```

**Second part of the HTML.**

```
<div class="popup-container hidden"><!-- many -->
  <div class="grid-item--popup-content" id="lending-creativity--popup">
    <button class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><span class="close-button--text-hidden">Close</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
~
```

**JavaScript**

```
let griditems       = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
let popupitems      = document.getElementsByClassName('popup-container');
let closebuttons    = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < griditems.length; i++) {
        griditems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            popupitems[i].style.display = "flex";
        })
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < griditems.length; i++) {
        closebuttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            closebuttons[i].style.display = "none";
        })
    }
})
```

I'm getting an error saying `closebuttons is not defined`.  I guess I'm not 100% sure I'm doing this the right way either, is this the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If they are the same length, why two loops?

Comment: Your second loop should use `i < closebuttons.length`

Comment: I suspect you misread the error message. It didn't say `closebuttons` is undefined, it said that `closebuttons[i]` is undefined. Because there are more grid items than close buttons.

Comment: @epascarello I see, you are right, I can do a single for loop and then two functions.  Good idea, thank you.

Comment: Thanks you all helped me to understand this better.  In the end I also decided that adding a class was a more effective way of controlling this so I simply added a hidden class or took it away to hide my popup.  If one of you wants to add the correct answer I will award you those tasty, tasty points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `closebuttons[i] is undefined`.  There were more griditems than close buttons.

I could also simplify my JavasScript as the loops should have been the same length.

```
let griditems       = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
let popupitems      = document.getElementsByClassName('popup-container');
let closebuttons    = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < griditems.length; i++) {
        griditems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            popupitems[i].style.display = "flex";
        })
        closebuttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            closebuttons[i].style.display = "none";
        })
    }
})
```

In the end I decided that instead of changing the style I could just add a class or remove it which would then keep my CSS in a CSS/SCSS file.  I found this more maintainable and non-tech staff members would could write CSS could easily change this if it was ever needed in the future.  It was also easier to maintain if we ever decided to use block instead of flex or something similar.  We could just edit it easily in the inspect element to see the outcomes.

Again my code could probably be simplified by not doing 2 loops.  But just in case they were different lengths I kept them in their own loops.

Here's my final code.

```
let griditems       = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item--link');
let popupitems      = document.getElementsByClassName('popup-container ');
let closebuttons    = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < griditems.length; i++) {
        griditems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            popupitems[i].classList.remove("hidden");
            popupitems[i].classList.add("shown");
        })
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < closebuttons.length; i++) {
        closebuttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            popupitems[i].classList.add("hidden");
            popupitems[i].classList.remove("shown");
        })
    }
})
```